# java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:org.apache.juli.logging.Log

Tags: maven, spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I'm getting the following error while I run docker image of my spring-boot app.

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.juli.logging.Log: Provider org.eclipse.jetty.apache.jsp.JuliLog not a subtype
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<init>(LogFactory.java:78)
        at org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:66)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsWebSocketContainer.<init>(WsWebSocketContainer.java:91)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsServerContainer.<init>(WsServerContainer.java:87)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.init(WsSci.java:131)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci.onStartup(WsSci.java:47)
```

Anybody please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Could you share a snippet of your docker file or docker-compose config file?

Comment: @ValerianPereira Now I'm not getting that error after deleting tomcat jars. Actually, I followed these instructions given on https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-springboot-kubernetes/index.html#0
I was able to complete up to 4th step of the tutorial, but after running 'docker run -ti --rm -p 8086:8086 gcr.io/$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT/synebiz:v1' command, I cannot get the preview